# Rails stripe integration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following railscast tutorial and I am facing with this error **Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1**.I am not able to understand how to remove this error .In URL I am specifying http://localhost:3000/subscriptions/new?plan_id=1

[subscriptioncontroller]

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

[subscriptions/new.html.erb]

```
<h1>Signing up for "<%= @subscription.plan.name %>"</h1>
<p>Includes <strong><%= @subscription.plan.kisses %> llama kisses</strong> for only <strong><%= number_to_currency @subscription.plan.price %></strong> per month!</p>

<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <% if @subscription.stripe_card_token.present? %>
    Credit card has been provided.
  <% else %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
      <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
      <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="stripe_error">
    <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a plan with an id of 1? ```rails c``` then ```Plan.find(1)```

Comment: Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a plan_id of 1 on the `#new` method because it doesn't exist yet.

If you run `rails c` and then `Plan.first.id` and get an error then you don't have any plan records yet and need to create them based upon however that railscast instructed you to. If you don't get an error then use that id it returns you in the console for your route

so

```
http://localhost:3000/subscriptions/new?plan_id=WHATEVER_THAT_ID_IS
```

Comment: showing error in view[subscription/new] undefined method `plan_id' for

Comment: run ```rails c ``` then ```Plan.first.id``` and tell me what you get

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):4
 from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
 from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
 from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
 from /home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

Comment: this is basically giving me nomethod error as i have listed above the following error when doing Plan.first.id

Comment: Okay, I am editing my answer. plz give me a ^vote if you feel i've helped you

Comment: actually the id is not generated thats why it is creating problem how to resolve that?